# Installed Windows 8 Pro from Dreamspark, but cannot confirm it is Windows 8 Pro

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have a copy of windows 8 pro from dreamspark through my university. But when I install it does not say pro anywhere. Is the install media currupted? or does it simply not tell you that its a pro?

My problem is that i just got a new Yoga 13 with a normal windows 8 version and hyper V is not included unless i go to the Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Head to your hot corner, click settings, and then PC Info. Your windows version will be under windows edition.

Comment: Its not a pro version installed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by going to control panel, system and upgrade and entered the key i had from dreamspark and it changed it to pro.

Comment: this by design. If you have an OEM Win8, the Key is embedded into the BIOS/UEFI. If you run setup, Win8 uses the OEM key and you get the Core Edition only if the OEM version is only the Core. In this case you always have to do the upgrade.

Comment: Would have been nice to know :) wasted a few hours on reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

On the Start screen, type winver, tap or click Apps, and then tap or click winver.exe.

Does the installed version have Bitlocker available?  Remote Desktop?  Provide the option to join a domain?  All of those are in Pro and might make it simple to determine version

Comment: will check when install process is complete. Just downloaded the ISO again from M$. (the version before was build 9800, i belive that was the RTM version). I had the RTM also and when downloaded the iso i pressed no to overwrite. So if they have named the iso with same names back when i got RTM and now, then that might be the error). Will find out in a few mins

Comment: The winver says windows 8 build 9800. version 6.2. Nothing about it being pro. no bitlocker. Something must be wrong with dreamspark.

Answer (score 0):

ISO SHA1 hashes from MSDN:

Windows 8 Pro VL (x86) - en_windows_8_pro_vl_x86_dvd_917830.iso
548AB51161FD83B889596B143D86C1EEB61EF2D0
Windows 8 Pro VL (x64) - en_windows_8_pro_vl_x64_dvd_917699.iso
6DDEDEBE40AB59CB11823F62F475C43C4053FE60
Windows 8 (multiple editions) (x86) - en_windows_8_x86_dvd_915417.iso 22D680EC53336BEE8A5B276A972CEBA104787F62
Windows 8 (multiple editions) (x64) - en_windows_8_x64_dvd_915440.iso
1CE53AD5F60419CF04A715CF3233F247E48BEEC4
Windows 8 Pro VL (x86) (Danish) - da_windows_8_pro_vl_x86_dvd_917829.iso
279246761402154861D0F4146C4317DF18491383
Windows 8 Pro VL (x64) (Danish) - da_windows_8_pro_vl_x64_dvd_917698.iso
85ADAB7F48FBEB0442130502DEEF28E9BA3A4D88
Windows 8 (multiple editions) (x86) (Danish) - da_windows_8_x86_dvd_915475.iso
83521A2746DC76760BD7096C1B5B50D70D201199
Windows 8 (multiple editions) (x64) (Danish) - da_windows_8_x64_dvd_915408.iso
A87824F9BE9B8D6139A7E615109CCE183BA48190

The "multiple editions" versions are ISOs with both Pro and standard.

You can get OS data from the command line with the command "wmic OS" or more specifically "wmic OS GET caption".

Comment: where did you find this, can i download the isos there too?.  I cant find names like that: Mine are Microsoft Windows 8 Professional 32/64-bit (English) - DreamSpark - Download

Comment: I have used the same media on my desktop machine earlier. When i check the info there it says pro. I dont see why it dont install the pro on my laptop. I installed it by starting setup from within the OS.

Comment: What OS did you upgrade from? Maybe the image you installed from is the Std/Pro one and it for some reason decided to use Std instead of Pro. I got the SHA1 hashes from MSDN which is a membership service like DreamSpark. I edited the post to add filenames as well. What you can do with the SHA1 hashes is use a SHA1 hashing program like SHA1deep from the [MD5deep](http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/) tools and compare the results of your ISO with the ones I posted. e.g. "sha1deep c:\dreamspark\windows8.iso" will give you a hash to compare with the ones I posted.

Comment: Okay. I upgraded from the std windows 8 that was on the laptop when i got it. And none of the iso's above matches mine.